# M1 Mac A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, apple-m1

I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/dantheman213/java-spring-gradle-docker-mvc-rest-starter-app) and attempted to run it on my M1 Mac by running the command `docker-compose up --build -d` in the terminal, and this was the output:

```
Building myapp
[+] Building 144.5s (13/14)                                                     
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 536B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:13              1.0s
 => [auth] library/openjdk:pull token for registry-1.docker.io             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.1s
 => => transferring context: 82.08kB                                       0.0s
 => [build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:13@sha256:08ab736e5b08665c  0.0s
 => CACHED [deploy 2/3] RUN mkdir -p /opt/app                              0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] RUN mkdir -p /workspace                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] WORKDIR /workspace                                  0.0s
 => [build 4/7] COPY . .                                                   0.0s
 => [build 5/7] RUN yum install -y wget unzip                             89.6s
 => [build 6/7] RUN wget -O /tmp/gradle.zip https://services.gradle.org/  49.4s
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN /opt/gradle/bin/gradle build                     4.4s 
------                                                                          
 > [build 7/7] RUN /opt/gradle/bin/gradle build:                                
#13 3.142                                                                       
#13 3.142 Welcome to Gradle 6.1!                                                
#13 3.142                                                                       
#13 3.143 Here are the highlights of this release:                              
#13 3.143  - Dependency cache is relocatable
#13 3.144  - Configurable compilation order between Groovy, Java & Scala
#13 3.144  - New sample projects in Gradle's documentation
#13 3.144 
#13 3.145 For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/release-notes.html
#13 3.145 
#13 4.047 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
#13 4.342 
#13 4.343 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
#13 4.344 
#13 4.344 * What went wrong:
#13 4.345 A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
#13 4.345 
#13 4.345 * Try:
#13 4.346 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
#13 4.348 
#13 4.348 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /opt/gradle/bin/gradle build]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'myapp' failed to build : Build failed
```

I added `platform: linux/amd64` to the docker-compose files, and made sure all the dependencies are installed, but I have no idea how to solve this problem. I tried terminating all Daemon processes, and this did not solve the problem either.

Comment: You should re-run this with --stacktrace and --debug so that you can get more insight into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I had to do the following to make it work:

1. Upgrading my [docker desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/) version seems to have fixed it.
2. Using amd64 architecture (`amd64/gradle:7.5.0-jdk18-alpine`) for the docker image

I hope it helps.